# I get an error message when unlocking an APFS FileVault volume with an Institutional Recovery Key

Tags: filevault, mobile-device-management

I'm testing an MDM solution (with an in house Server.app MDM instance), which enforces FileVault. It's setup with both an Institutional Recovery Key (IRK) and a Personal Recovery Key (PRK). The last one is also saved to MDM.

Basically, we generated a keychain like this, exported the certificate from the keychain, and added it to an MDM profile (we're using Server.app's MDM).

It's working great. When I do a `diskutil apfs listCryptoUsers diskNxM`, I get all the users I expect, including an user of type `Institutional Recovery User` and one with type `Institutional Recovery External Key`. Resetting password via Open Directory works fine. Unlocking the drive with the PRK works fine.

And now I'm testing to unlock the volume with the said IRK.
I booted via Recovery (cmd+R), and when I execute `diskutil apfs unlockVolume /dev/diskNsM -recoveryKeyChain /Volumes/RecoveryDrive/FileVaultMaster.keychain` (the keychain is unlocked, and the drive is correct), I get this error:

```
Error unlocking APFS Volume: The external-to-APFS security system's credential-unwrap
operation failed (-69534)
```

I checked unlocking the keychain using a different password, and that failed directly. [Someone here](https://www.jamf.com/jamf-nation/discussions/12961/deploying-the-filevault-institutional-key) suggested to remove the certificate from the keychain. This didn't work either. I double checked the volume was APFS. It was.

Any idea's (besides creating a new FileVault Master keychain and do the whole process one more time)?

Answer (score 1):

The thing I forgot to mention was I didn't generate the Keychain myself. I started off with a keychain with a certificate and private key that I could unlock, and an MDM profile with the exported certificate.

Because I couldn't find another solution, I created a new Keychain. I used [this Apple Support Document](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202385). I didn't remove the private key, because I deploy it by exporting the certificate, and distributing it via MDM.

However, I did use the *"Use the private key to unlock a user's startup disk"* procedure from this document to unlock the volume and it worked!

So this is not an actual answer to the asked question, but certainly a solution. I double checked the computer encrypted with the old keychain certificate with this procedure, but got the same error message. So probably there was something wrong with the keychain and/or certificate...